# HTML5 <video> does not load

Tags: html, video

I'm creating a webpage that is using HTML5 for videos. I tried one video, and it loaded and played successfully. But then, the other video does not even load. How can I fix this? The code is the same for the  working video and the not working video

```
<video src="SnakeVids/sukyandaru.mp4" width="350" height="300" controls="controls" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Btw, the difference is that the first video is a `.mp4`, and the other one I converted from `.flv` to `.mp4`.

Comment: what browser did you test this in?

Comment: As @EduardGamonal said - in which browser are you testing your video? Also: Does the browser play the video, when you enter the URL directly into the address bar?

Comment: i'm testing it on google chrome . and @insertusernamehere, it does not even play .

Comment: In that case it seems that the file is corrupt or the URL is wrong.

Comment: how about the codecs you used when you converted flv to mp4? the video tag doesn't support all codecs, although chrome has support for mp4 and firefox doesn't.

Comment: the file plays when i play it on a media player(vlc, windows media player). does it have something to do with renaming ? i renamed the second file .

Comment: you mean that the name of the file doesn't match the `src` attribute?

Comment: in the src, i used the name that it is currently renamed .

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, it looks like your video was converted into a format that is not compatible with Google Chrome. [MP4 supports some codecs](http://www.mp4ra.org/codecs.html) but only a [small subset is widely supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14#Data_streams), and [Chrome supports these video formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) for the `<video>` tag.
You should encode your video using a supported codec.

Additionally, you might want to provide different sources for compatibility with other browsers and platforms.`ogg` is a safe choice. A simplified example extracted from w3schools:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

You can also use third-party libraries, like [videoJS](http://www.videojs.com/), that will help you with video formats support. Some of them even have a flash fallback.